# Не получается удалить MySql на ubuntu 18.04. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libevent-core-2.1-6 libhtml-template-perl mysql-client-5.7
  mysql-client-core-5.7 mysql-common mysql-server-5.7 mysql-server-core-5.7
Suggested packages:
  libipc-sharedcache-perl mailx tinyca
E: Could not get lock /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/cache/apt/archives/
```

Вот что выдавал при установке mysql-server и те же самые ошибки при установке mysql-workbench. Устанавливаю такой командой: sudo apt-get install mysql-server/mysql-workbench. Команды брал с оф. сайта и руководство по установке оттуда же.

После выполнил эти команды и заново установил mysql-server:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Начал выдавать следующую ошибку:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Нашел в интернете: проблема связано с тем, что остались на компе зависимости и какие-то конф. файлы. Просматриваю dpkg -l

```
ic  mysql-common   5.8+1.0.4    all          MySQL database common files, e.g.
iHR mysql-server-5 5.7.24-0ubun amd64        (no description available)
ic  mysql-utilitie 1.6.4-1      all          collection of scripts for managin
```

Нахожу то, что нужно удалить, но не получается это сделать, пробовал такую команду:

```
sudo apt-get purge имяПакета
```

Вот что показывает на этот раз:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Удалил следующей командой 2 из 3. Получилось удалить mysql-common && mysql-utilities

```
sudo dpkg --purge имяПакета
```

Но когда хочу удалить последний пакет(mysql-server-5.7), то вот, что выдает:

```
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.7 (--purge):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.7
```

Пытался переустановить командой:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Вот, что выдал:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.7 : PreDepends: mysql-common (>= 5.5) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-client-5.7 (>= 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-common (>= 5.8+1.0.4~) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: mysql-server-core-5.7 (= 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Пакет только этот остался по идее, как его удалить не пойму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась максимально смешно. Я просто перезагрузил комп и выполнил upgrade. Все файлы mysql установились обратно, я их спокойно удалил и теперь заново можно поставить без всяких ошибок, наверное)
P.S. В любой непонятной ситуации перезагружай комп.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что у вас на момент попытки удаления пакета был запущен процесс, блокирующий файлы, которые требуется удалить. Комп не обязательно было перезагружать, можно было просто завершить этот процесс (хотя, если вы затрудняетесь его найти, то перезагрузиться конечно проще).

Comment: Я завершал все процессы с помощью stop и после проверял запущенные процессы, все равно не срабатывало..

Comment: На будущее. От root удалите `/var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

Comment: @Andrey, тогда когда возникает подобная проблема?